# Additional security group in EKS managed node group

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I need a help with EKS managed node group.
I've created a cluster with one additional sg. Inside of this cluster I've created managed node group. All code is stocked in terraform. Once managed node group creates new instance, only one security group is attached (SG created by AWS). Is it somehow a way to attach also additional security group to instances?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Are you trying to attach pre-existing security groups or security groups that the terraform template **will** create?

Comment: You can follow this example https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/v17.24.0/examples/complete, this eks module supports worker_security_group_id and worker_additional_security_group_ids. You need to create resource "aws_security_group" and add it to the module.

Answer (score 5):

By default EKS compute mode group, will have the default cluster Security Group attached which is created by AWS. Even if you provide additional security group to EKS cluster during the creation, that additional security group will not be attached to compute instances. So, to get this working, you have to use Launch Templates.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom launch template to define your own security group for the node group. You can then reference the launch template in your terraform `aws_eks_node_group` resource.

```bash
 launch_template {
   name = aws_launch_template.your_eks_launch_template.name
   version = aws_launch_template.your_eks_launch_template.latest_version
  }
```